# sql ordering columns query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id     product_cat_id     product_type_id          ordering
1          1                  1                       1
2          2                  3                       1
3          1                  2                       1
4          1                  1                       2
5          3                  1                       1
```

I want to order by product_cat_id then product_type_id from the ordering column. The output should be this:

```
id     product_cat_id     product_type_id          ordering
1          1                  1                       1
4          1                  1                       2
3          1                  2                       1
2          2                  3                       1
5          3                  1                       1
```

Comment: This is really basic sql. Did you spend more than 2 seconds researching this?

Comment: I did but I couldn't think of exactly how to phase my google search which is why I had to give an example on stack overflow. Did this question really deserve a thumbs down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the ORDER BY modifier. You can string together multiple fields separated by commas.

Ex:

```
    SELECT id, product_cat_id, product_type_id, ordering FROM table ORDER BY product_cat_id, product_type_id, ordering
```

This would sort by product cat_id, then product_type_id, then ordering.

Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you!!! This did exactly what I wanted!!! I need to wait 10 mins before I can accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the query:

```
order by product_cat_id, product_type_id
```

Is that what you're asking? I don't get what the "ordering" column is doing there.